# How to set php session value from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

i want to set php session value from javascript
i know it is not possible to do from javascript so i made this code

javascript:

```
 window.open("test.php?s=1");
```

php:

```
session_start();
    if(!empty($_GET['s'])) {
        $_SESSION['test']= $_GET['s'];
    }
```

it is working and all but only problem is that it opens new window and user have to close it

is it possible to do something like that without opening new window?
i know it is possible to do with xmlhttp.open but it didn't really worked for me + i have no idea how to use it, tried to understand it by searching info in google but couldn't so i figured out that this way i am doing is the simples for me just need to do it without opening new window

Comment: Have you looked into ajax?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How about using AJAX?

JS:

```js
var params = {"s":1};
$.ajax({
    data:  params,
    url:   'set_global.php',
    type:  'post',
    success:  function (response) {
        
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['s'])) {
    $_SESSION['test']= $_POST['s'];
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you, i always thought that AJAX is hard and was afraid of using it, you just proved that i was wrong

Comment: Can you please show me an example of getting php value like SESSION to javascript using AJAX? I was looking in google for that but couldn't understand how..

Comment: @ArtisLaizans Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax for this:-

```
    $.ajax({url: "test.php", data: 's=1', success: function(result){
        //if need to code else don't
    }});
```

Comment: But how can i get like same SESSION value from php to javascript using AJAX? I was looking for that but didn't really get how can anyone please show example?

Comment: $.ajax({url: "test.php", data: 'action=get_s', success: function(result){
         alert(result);
    }});
php:-
if( isset($_GET['action']) &&  $_GET['action'] == 'get_s') {
   echo $_SESSION['test'];
  exit;
}

Comment: please vote up, if it helps you and make it correct.